# jQuery: accessing a single instance of a class in a dynamically created table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have many auto-generated table and those tables have a `<span class="productNumber">` element in the `thead` that shows the number of products in the table. (right now this is done in php via `<?php count($products); ?>`).

I wrote a filter to help users to navigate those tables. The filter allows the user to choose a product category and all `tr` elements that don't have this product category get the Bootstrap class `hidden`.

I now want to use jQuery to count the actually visible elements for each table and display the number of elements that are actually visible.

My current approach is this:

```
$('table').each(function(){
    let counter = 0;
    $('tr', this).each(function(){
        if (this.hasClass("hidden")) {
            counter++;
        };
    });
    $('.productNumber').html(counter);
})
```

The problem is that this overwrites all `.productNumber` elements with the same value (the number of visible products in the very last `table`).

I tried modifying it in various ways (`$('.productNumber', this)`, `$('.productNumber')[0]`, etc.), but wasn't able to write only to the current `table`'s `.productNumber`.

Comment: Side note: You don't need to calc `counter`, just `$('tr.hidden', this).length` should give you the desired number

Answer (score 0):

The easy way to do this:

```
$("table").each(function(){
    var count = $(this).find("tr:not([class*='hidden'])").size();
    $(this).find(".productNumber").first().html(count);
});
```

English Translation:

```
For each table: 
    Get the number of tr's that don't have "hidden" defined in 
    it's class attribute and assign to the count variable.
    Find the first ".productNumber" cell in the table and set its
    content
```

Answer (score 0):

use this selector

```
$(this).children('.productNumber').html(counter);
```

Comment: Should use `find()`, `children()` will only get direct descendants.

Comment: it is a descendant element class of table.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Answer (score 0):

My proof of concept. https://jsfiddle.net/dewwwald/8gn5jdsL/1/

The issue is solved by specifying the this to the product number lookup.
assuming productNumber is inside the tr. Also as you describe your requirements I read that `this.hasClass("hidden")` should have a ! so `!this.hasClass("hidden")`.

```
$('table').each(function(){
  let _this = this;
  _this.counter = 0;
  $('tr', _this).each(function(){
    if (!this.hasClass("hidden")) {
        _this.counter++;
    };
    $('.productNumber', this).html(_this.counter);
  });

})
```